# php artisan returns "]" character on every command

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

When i run

```
php artisan serve
```

` i get

```
]Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
```

Note the ] character. I recently installed`vinkla/laravel-pusher` package so I thought it was a problem but removing the package didnot do the trick. So what might actually be the problem. I haven't changed other files. I am running php 7.0 on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by migrating the project to a new laravel project. And unregistering some service providers.